# Any way to open a maybe malicious website without having to use a VM?

Tags: websites, protection

Sometimes there are websites I'd like to checkout but I have the feeling that the site may have something malicious in it, the easiest way would be to just load my VM and opening the site there, but thats a hassle sometimes, specially if I just want to do a quick check. Not saying that because of lazyness of having to load a VM I would risk my stuff, but is there a more light way like a browser that works as a VM ?

Comment: Open it in an up to date browser and don't download anything.

Answer (score 2):

Security is a trade-off, if you are not willing to take extra steps to protect yourself, then you need to accept the risks.

**Security level: basic.** Open the website in your browser with Javascript turned off. A plugin like NoScript for Firefox is going to be even more useful, because it can also block iframes and fonts.

**Security level: high.** Open the website in a virtual machine, also taking the steps shown above (JS disabled).

**Security level: extreme.** Find an online service that can make HTTP requests and fetch the source code of the web page. If you google it, you'll find some free ones. It's like running `curl`, but on somebody else's machine. After you see the source code, you can read the text content, check the code, spot suspicious parts, fetch or remove any additional resources (CSS, JS, etc.)

Comment: Conntainer (Docker) would be a little bit less secure than VM with the benefit of using less resources and starting faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can scan URLs on virus total: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/url